# Is this translation correct? Or is it saying "Even with that, we can't do this" instead of "Without that, we can't do this"?

Tags: translation

Is this translation correct?

[image: 遺伝子操作を問わず]

[image]

Or is it supposed to be "Even with genetic manipulation and posterior education, creating a Level 5 is impossible?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Even with genetic manipulation and posterior education, creating a
Level 5 is impossible?"` is correct.
`問う` usually means `ask` but sometimes it also means `matter` (verb). So `問わず` means `it doesn't matter`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better translation might be:

> Even with genetic manipulation and education, forcing the generation of a Level 5 from a cloned body is impossible.

I eliminated posterior because the phrase "posterior education", though I understand it, is not typically said in English.

Regarding the use of "force", 発生させる is a causative verb so this sentence is talking about "causing" creation rather than creation in general.  I suspect this sentence comes after the speaker made a lot of attempts and finally decided that he cannot "make" the act of creation happen. I don't think he's actually saying that it cannot happen as the translation suggests.

Hope this helps

Comment: Regarding 発生させる - This sentence is about a kind of people "超能力「者」" On the other hand, 発生 is not used for people. It is like a paper on biology. Actually 発生させる implies that the sentence was written by a mad scientist who consider 超能力者 as pure research objects, or by someone who wants to exploit them as tools.

Comment: @Hideki Interesting.  Thanks for the comment!